# Convert Jquery to javascript(AJAX)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can i get the same result but instead of jquery use vanilla javascript;

Using ajax with jquery I manage to send the value from input to node js.

```
**/script/main.js**
 
///Search ajax call
let searchResults = document.getElementById('search_in_platform_functionality');
  if(searchResults){
     searchResults.addEventListener('keyup',(dataSearch)=>{

     let searchValue = dataSearch.target.value.trim();
      searchRes(searchValue);
   })
}

function searchRes(searchTerm){
    $.get(url,{search:searchTerm},(results)=>{
     console.log(results)
  });
}
```

**/controller.js**

```
 router.get("/", async (req, res)=>{
    var searchObject = req.query;
    console.log(searchObject)
    if(req.query.search !== undefined){
        searchObject = {
           $or:[
             {firstName:{$regex: req.query.search,$options:"i"}},
             {lastName:{$regex: req.query.search,$options:"i"}},
             {username:{$regex: req.query.search,$options:"i"}}
           ]
       }
    }
    await  User.find(searchObject).then(results =>{
      res.status(200).send(results);
  }).catch(error =>{
     console.log(error);
     res.sendStatus(400);

  })
});
```

[image]

How to get the same result sorted parameters in the node server but with javascript focus vanilla without jquery.

```
let search = new XMLHttpRequest();
search.open('GET', url,{search:searchTerm},(results)=>{
        console.log(results)
});
search.send();
```

I tried something like that but it doesn't work.

Comment: Use the more modern [fetch() API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: ok i will try this right now

Comment: fetch('url',{search:searchTerm},(results)=>{
                console.log(results)
        })

Comment: something right that,but isn't work

Comment: You need to do more reading on how to use `fetch()`. That syntax is simply incorrect. There are examples in the docs and you should easily find numerous tutorials

Comment: ok,I will read the documentation,there are more information that I dont understood,thanks for advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take on the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API),

```
fetch(`url?search=${searchTerm}`).then(response => response.json()).then(results => {
    console.log(results);
}).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

You're sending a `GET` method, so you need to pass the parameters in the URL query string

The `.then` callback is run when the `Promise` is completed. You can have as many `.then()` callbacks as you want, but the first two are necessary for you to access the return data. [MDN Promise.prototype.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Then the fetch's body is passed in the first callback, then you use on of its methods to convert the result into an object or array or text that you can use in your code `.json()` or `.text()` or `.formData()` or `.blob()` or `.arrayBuffer()` read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body)

the last `.then` callback is where the result is passed through for you to manipulate it.

You can pass a `.catch` callback in case there's an error and you need it to be logged. [MDN Promise.prototype.catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)

Comment: it,s works,let me undestood you take the url and pass the seatchTerm as a query ,well using this is allow me to use in node server req.query and to access this query.

Comment: Using it in node, you'll still have to require it like const fetch = require('fetch');. I've edited my code to explain more on the `Fetch API`